# How can I reverse an ASCII character array?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, reverse, gnu-assembler

The objective of this program is inverting, or reversing, an array. For example, if I have "Hello, world!" the program is supposed to print "!dlrow ,olleH".
But instead of doing so, the program prints: "!dlrow world!". Can someone explain to me why?

My code so far is:

```
.data          

msg:    .ascii    "Hello, world!\n"

len = . - msg

_start:

movl $msg, %eax
movl $len, %ebx
dec %ebx
dec %ebx
save:

movb msg(%ebx), %dl
mov %dl, (%eax)
inc %eax
dec %ebx
jnz save

movl $len,%edx
movl $msg,%ecx         
movl $1,%ebx
movl $WRITE,%eax      # pedir write ao sistema
int  $LINUX_SYSCALL   # chama o sistema

movl $0,%ebx
movl $EXIT,%eax       # pedir exit ao sistema
int  $LINUX_SYSCALL   # chama o sistema
```

Comment: Just think what the code does. Then take a debugger and run it through. Or take paper and draw the letters and run the code in your head.

Comment: Maybe because you should be **swapping** the characters in msg(%ebx)with what is at (%eax) . If you step through with a debugger like _GDB_ you'd be able to look at memory and watch what happens in your loop. Using a debugger is a valuable skill.

Comment: Not Linux but the algorithm will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583860/unable-to-reverse-string-in-8086-masm/36584815#36584815

Comment: ..and after you correct the swap there remains the classic "howler" where you traverse the *whole* string, swapping it back to where it all was. Two pointers or indices: inc/dec until they meet in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux assembly reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423816/linux-assembly-reverse-a-string)

Comment: Set the direction flag, use rep movsb and unset the flag?